# JavaScript mutation observer not node error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

im using a mutation observer to detect changes in a  element with class of `rt__body scrollbar-dark`. but im getting this error Uncaught `TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` please help fix it.

Below is my JavaScript code

```
function obser1() {
    const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
            if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
                console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0]);
            }
        })
    });
    console.log("obs1");
    const trades = document.querySelector('rt__body scrollbar-dark');
    observer.observe(trades, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
        attributes: true,
        characterData: true
    })
    console.log("observed");
}
window.setTimeout(btn4, 1000);
window.setTimeout(obser1, 2300);
```

Here is my manifest code

```
 "name": "Bybit orderbook color",
  "version": "1.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "https://www.bybit.com/trade/usdt/BTCUSDT" ],
      "css": [ "Style.css" ],
      "run_at": "document_idle",
      "js": [ "background.js" ]

    }

  ],

  "permissions": [ "activeTab" ]


}
```

Comment: The selector `"rt__body scrollbar-dark"` will search for an element `<scrollbar-dark>` which is a decendent of an other element `<rt__body>`.  Class selector starts with a dot `.`.